# VHDL Is there a way to read the current delta during a simulation

Tags: vhdl

I'm building a package generator with various stimuli settings. The generator asserts data at Delta 0 by default. I would like to control shift this to other Deltas, is there a way to read what "time" (delta) its at ?

**Description**

Its to test a transceiver made in VHDL using the Avalon streaming interface from Altera (intel).

So the packages I'm talking about is the data transmitted by this transceiver.
The generator here will generate the basic package and send it the the transmitter interface which in turn will send it to the receiver and then to a monitor where the package is checked for errors.

```
| Gen | -> | Tx | -> | Rx | -> | Mon |
```

The clock is set to run at 0 delta because that made sense to me. 
Now the data generate by this clock would in real hardware be triggered at the next clock period. however if the data is generate at 0 delta it will trigger immediately. Therefor I need to shift the Data generation away from zero delta. That could be done by moving it 1 delta or 1 time unit in my case 1 ps or 1 ns.

I am using a synchronize to align my generator with its monitor. The complexity of this (1700 lines of code) generator involves storing the packages with different attributes and comparing it on the monitor side for protocol and data errors, being able to insert it at different points on our transmission line and insert and setup different stimuli and package configurations.

Regards

Comment: Hi, I believe the only way to look at what is changing in delta "time" is by using the step command (in vivado) where youexecute the code one line at a time! This doesnt giev you  any visual output in the simulation waveform table but it shows you which bits are calculated first. Hope this helps!

Comment: @lewisthegruffalo That is just a code debugging tool, and has nothing to do with delta cycles.

Comment: @Ephreal No, you cannot track what delta you are on. You can see the current simulation time by using the NOW function, but not which delta. Is there any reason you need delta accuracy? what are you actually trying to do/measure? If you are creating a package, how do you know anything you have is being called at time 0?

Comment: @Tricky - its a very complex package generator and it get synced to the clock before starting and then im only using wait for "time" instead of parsing my clock into the procedure. The clock changes at 0 delta. But if my data also changes at 0 delta it will trigger there and not give the correct picture. However I have fixed it by shifting it 1 ps instead of a Delta. I am still unclear if this makes the simulator switch down in resolution and then increase its run time. I am using Riviera pro

Comment: @Ephreal When you say package, do you actually mean packet (as opposed to a VHDL package)? What is the reason for not wanting to be synchronised to the clock? What happens if the clock doesnt toggle at delta 0? what about resets? have you considered using the 'transaction attribute to synchronise things?

Comment: @Ephreal Also, can you clarify why it is a complex packet generator? What type of packets is it generating?

Comment: @Tricky I have added a small description of what the generator is. Also the reason for not synchronizing to the clock is more of a personal preference as not to have an extra signal in my procedure.

Comment: @Ephreal It sounds like you're trying to combine data generation and interface into one - which makes for less re-useable code. Much better if you can seaparate the data from the interface. EG. have the data generator throw out an array of bytes, and then have some form of BFM that can convert this byte array into the transactions that actually occur on the interface. That way you can send the same data over several interfaces. Also, are you talking about a physical layer transceiver (ie to transmit between two FPGAs) or internal?

Comment: @Tricky Well it is more or less what I am doing. I have one procedure which generates an array with all the byte data and then a procedure which does all the signal wiggling. The code is reusable in the sense that it can be inserted at any point in our transmission line. Though its not reusable in the sense its a proprietary protocol. The interface is an Avalon ST but with a few more constraints.

Comment: Delta cycles are used to order signal updates at the same simulation time (e.g., no **after** present in a signal waveform assignment) emulating parallelism in sequential statements. With no signal updates scheduled for the current simulation time, simulation time is advanced to the next simulation time an event is scheduled. You can't count delta cycles by inference from a signal event representing simulation time (e.g. a clock) without causing them (Schrödinger's simulation cycles). Your communications should be signal event driven or ordered by simulation time, both using wait statements.

Comment: @ user1155120 your answering my question, but so did Tricky. But i do not agree. you a signals attributes without it causing an event or delta. IE the variable Test and signal Test1 -> Test := Test1'LAST_EVENT. I was asking if there was also one that could give me the current delta. Also you can use **after** to shift your deltas. But as I told Tricky i found an alternative.

Comment: @user1155120. I do not think its an XY Problem because I asked about X because I did not have a solution for that. and was told X is not possible so I found solution Y. That is not what is specified in the XY problem your linking. But I guess others will judge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was, since its was not possible to get current delta infomation, to insert a 1 ps delay instead of 0 ps delay. This makes a real time shift of the data compared to the clock.